# listings in a footnote

Tags: listings, footnotes

This code won't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\small
}

\begin{document}
lorem ipsum\footnote{%
\begin{lstlisting}
// some C code or whatever...
printf("Blah blah\n");
\end{lstlisting}}
\end{document}
```

It says `Illegal parameter number in definition of \lst@insertargs.` I know `listings` is really picky about where it goes, but there *must* be a way to cram a listing into a footnote, right?

(This is a MWE and my tex files are a bit more complex; my actual error is `Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.` but they are hopefully related; I couldn't get this error with the MWE.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another option is to use the `cprotect` package, and replace `\footnote` by `\cprotect\footnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\small
}

\begin{document}
lorem ipsum\cprotect\footnote{%
\begin{lstlisting}
// some C code or whatever...
printf("Blah blah\n");
\end{lstlisting}}
\end{document}
```

The main advantage is that many macros can be `\cprotect`-ed in the same way as footnote. The main disadvantage is that it will (currently) produce one auxiliary file per `\cprotect`-ed command.

You can find this [package on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cprotect/) (it is rather new).

Answer (score 7):

`\usepackage{bigfoot}` should do the trick.  It does a lot more than that, but making footnote texts be parsed only once (like plain TeX does with its own `\footnote` macro) is among them.

If you want more lightweight answers (most requiring more manual work, but not meddling with LaTeX's internals all that much), https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin gives some.

Answer (score 4):

A fail-proof way for passing around listings (and other verbatim material) that furthermore works without any extra packages or experimental features is to employ a box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\small
}

\newsavebox{\LstBox}

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\LstBox}
\begin{lstlisting}
// some C code or whatever...
printf("Blah blah\n");
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
%
lorem ipsum\footnote{\usebox{\LstBox}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great!

Answer (score 3):

The listings author describes the difficulties in using listings in arguments and offers an "experimental" way of handling it (see page 46 of the user manual).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\small
}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
lorem\footnote{\lstinline{var i:integer;} and
\lstinline!protected\ \ spaces! and
\fbox{\lstinline!\\\{\}\%!}} 
ipsum  \VerbatimFootnotes
  We can put verbatim\footnote{\verb+_Yes!_+} text in footnotes
\end{document}
```

You can also use the package `fancyvrb`,  which offers a `\VerbatimFootnote`, as shown in the minimal above.