# Listing code in footnote in Latex

Tags: footnotes

I have the piece of code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                 xmlns:ex="http://www.example.org/" >
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.org/Heitor_Villa-Lobos">  
    <ex:origem rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/Rio_de_Janeiro"/> 
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
\end{lstlisting}
```

and I want to show it in the footnote. I've tried to use

```
\footnote{
\begin{lstlisting}
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                 xmlns:ex="http://www.example.org/" >
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.org/Heitor_Villa-Lobos">  
    <ex:origem rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/Rio_de_Janeiro"/> 
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
\end{lstlisting}
```

}

I've added an extra bracket "{}" to protect the content, but it doesn't work, too. When I run this I get the following error: "Argument of \lst@next has an extra }. }".

Does anyone could help me?

TIA

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a discussion on listings in footnotes [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10218/listings-in-a-footnote).

One of the simplest solutions would be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newsavebox{\LstBox}

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\LstBox}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=XML, basicstyle=\footnotesize]
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                 xmlns:ex="http://www.example.org/" >
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.org/Heitor_Villa-Lobos">  
    <ex:origem rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/Rio_de_Janeiro"/> 
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
%
This is some text\footnote{This is the listing in the footnote:\par\usebox{\LstBox}}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: output]

If highlighting etc. is needed, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195414/correctly-highlighting-custom-html-tags-in-listings/195450#195450) for one example of XML highlighting with listings which would combine with your code to give:

[image: highlighted output]