# \UseVerbatim equivalent for lstlisting

Tags: verbatim, lstlisting

The package `fancyvrb` provides `\begin{SaveVerbatim}` and `\UseVerbatim`, which does almost exactly what I need. I want to use this with a custom `lstlisting` environment. The environment looks exactly how I want it, with the backgroundcolor and everything (it's quite involved).

So what I need is some sort of `\begin{SaveLstlisting}` and `\UseLstlisting`, so I can store the contents of a lstlisting environment in a macro at one point and use it at a later point. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49418/?

Comment: Apparently it suppresses page breaks. Any idea how to allow page breaks in listings using this method?

Comment: What is your use case exactly? Maybe there are easier ways to do what you want. If you don't want to repeat long code fragments then you could save the code to a file and use `\lstinputlisting`. If you want to store the settings of the colors, fonts etc. then you can use `\lstdefinestyle` and use the defined style for multiple code fragments.

Comment: I want to use text snippets, which display a code listing (or several listings) that is always different. It should work something like this: `\usesnippet{snippetA}{listingOne}{listingTwo}` where listingOne and listingTwo refer to a different listing each. I guess it could work with an extra file, but it would be nice if I could do it without that. Maybe the `filecontents` will do what I need? I just had that idea.